# How to spread div blocks in a page?

Tags: html, css

I was looking at Android developer's website and I wanted to copy how they designed the article's animation when someone hovered on top of it. As such I tried to make something similar in plain HTML/CSS. However, I am running into an issue.

I used float expecting that the div tags would seperate from one another and apply the appropriate margins. However, It seems that the div tags are stacking on top of each other instead of being spread out.

I wanted them to look like this

[image]

but it ended up looking like this

https://codepen.io/alfielytorres/project/full/XYxPVO

I provided my files below.

HTML

```
  <div class="new"><div>
  <div class="new"><div>
  <div class="new"><div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background: white;
  font-family:courier;
  padding:20px 100px 20px 100px; 
}

.new {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:white;
   position: relative;
  border:2px solid black;
  float:left;
  padding:15px;
  border-radius:5%;
}

.new::before {
  content:"";
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
   padding:15px;
  background-color:black;
  position:absolute;
  transform:translate(-6px,-6px);
  border-radius:5%;
  z-index: -1;
  
  
}

.new:hover:before{
  animation-name:click;
  animation-duration:500ms;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}



@keyframes click { 
   0% { 
         transform:translate(-6px,-6px);
  
  }
  100% { 
         transform:translate(-10px,-10px);
  
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close your div tags like so `</div>`, then you could put these 3 div in a flex container and space them evenly.

hope this helps